# Javascript countdown timer is erratic

Tags: javascript, php

I have a raspberry pi that initiates a garage door close event after a 90s delay. I have been successful in showing the countdown timer dynamically update on a web page but for some reason the countdown is erratic and constantly flickers with lower and then higher numbers.

Clearly I must be refreshing something but needless to say I have spent many hours on forums but to no avail. I am hoping that someone can look at my code and give me some direction.

---

```
<?php 
$pinInput = trim(shell_exec("gpio read 26"));
$pinOutput = trim(shell_exec("gpio read 2"));

if ($pinInput!=$pinOutput){

echo "Timing for auto reclose...";

?>

<br>

<b><span id="countdown">90</span> Seconds</b>

<script type="text/javascript">

var timer = 90,
    el = document.getElementById('countdown');

(function t_minus() {
    'use strict';
    el.innerHTML = timer--;
    if (timer >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            t_minus();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        // do stuff, countdown has finished.
    }
}());

</script>

<?php

}

elseif ($pinInput=1)
{
echo "Monitoring input...";
}
else
{
echo "Garage door is closing...";
}
?>
```

I should also mentioned that the above piece of code is within a file called timing.php. This is called on index.php as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#Input').load('timing.php');
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
</script>
```

So in summary, what I would like is for "Timing for auto recluse..." to remain static if ($pinInput!=$pinOutput) but dynamically shown the countdown from 90s.

Comment: 1) Are you calling `t_minus` anywhere else? It sounds like you have a couple of different asynchronous functions running. 2) You'll want to change `$pinInput=1` to `$pinInput == 1`. `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: You're reloading that `timing.php` page once every second, and *inside* that code you're then re-starting that timeout process. You're basically starting up lots and lots of redundant timers.

Answer (score 1):

First let's look at this code, the last bit in your question:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () {
        $('#Input').load('timing.php');
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
```

That sets up an **interval** timer that will load the "timing.php" URL into the page once per second.

Now, here's part of what you say is returned from "timing.php":

```
var timer = 90,
el = document.getElementById('countdown');

(function t_minus() {
    'use strict';
    el.innerHTML = timer--;
    if (timer >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            t_minus();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        // do stuff, countdown has finished.
    }
}());
```

So when the browser receives the response from "timer.php", jQuery will run that code. That sets up a repeating timer function — essentially the same thing as an interval timer, except that it stops itself after a while).

Now, when that code is reloaded, you **don't** get new global variables `timer` and `el`. The global variables already defined by the last load of "timer.php" will simply have their values overridden. That means that the already-in-process *previous* timeout sequence will suddenly see `timer` set back to `90`.

It's not clear exactly what it is you intend to do. Perhaps that `setInterval()` is just superfluous, and all you need to do is just load "timeout.php" once. Or, perhaps when the "timeout.php" code loads, it first needs to wipe out any already-running timeout loops, though that seems odd since those are set up to wind down only after 90 seconds.